# ChangeBounds Android Transition

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-view, android-transitions

I have a recyclerview in my app, and each row contains a button which shows a text in the same cell, under the button. I have used ChangeBounds transition to make the text appear with a smooth animation, increasing the row height until the text is completely shown. So when a button is clicked, I do:

```
 TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(row, transition)
 holder.hiddenText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

It works well, but whith a problem. The hidden text appears with an animation which increases its height, as expected. But the row height is not animated, and it jumps from the original height until the final height without any animation.

Is there any way to achieve a height transition over the row, to increase at the same time as the text?

Comment: If you want animation to take effect for `row` also, then you need to perform `beginDelayedTransition()` on a one layer higher of the `row`, which in your case maybe is the actual `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @azizbekian Thanks a lot, that solved my problem!

Comment: @VictorManuelPinedaMurcia Can you show me your final code please. I have the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want animation to take effect for `row` also, then you need to perform `beginDelayedTransition()` on a one layer higher of the `row`, which in your case maybe is the actual `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your row's layout

```
public static void expand(final View v) {
    v.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final int targetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    // Older versions of android (pre API 21) cancel animations for views with a height of 0.
    v.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = new Animation()
    {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                    ? LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    : (int)(targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
            v.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    // 1dp/ms
    a.setDuration((int)(targetHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
```

Linear or Relative layout of row's will animate and expand. Hope this solves your problem